# where I can change the links to social icons in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, social-media

I do not know Joomla, but I had one task in exsiting site, to change the link of social button, linkedin.
I thought it was simple task, but I wasted 2 days for it, looking in files and interface. Can you help me please, or just give me ideas where these social links can be placed.

version of Joomla is 2.5.14

```
<div class="custom">
    <p style="text-align: right;">
<a href="/index.php/sitemap" target="_self" style="color: #1d8ba3;">Site Map</a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/ats-shipping-llc/59/529/6" target="_blank"><img src="/images/siteImages/lnicon.png" border="0" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance)
you are my last chance :)

Comment: please provide any reference link and which template or extension are you using?

Comment: sorry, I refreshed the question , and http://www.atsworld.co/  this is the link of site. I do not know exactly, there is plugin JA T3, but I guess these links written staticaly.

Comment: probably thats a custom module, Just check the backend for the custom module and edit the links :)

Comment: that sounds very simple from you)) but I rechecked this module, and 2 other modules, I thought it is written in some template. could not you point where exactly I can look for ?)

Comment: have you checked *index.php* in your default template?

Comment: yes, there is just checking for class T3Template and setting, rendering a T3Template, and something about that JAT3 framework plugin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the links in Module Custom HTML module, in administration panel.